# Qual a melhor maneira de se utilizar as dependências do Node?

Tags: node.js, npm

**Introdução:**
Vamos a um exemplo prático, pra que fique simples de se entender...
Eu quero usar o framework ***Bulma*** em meu projeto, sendo assim rodo o seguinte comando:

```
 $ npm install --save-dev bulma
```

Tchanram! Agora eu consigo encontrar tanto o arquivo *bulma.css* completo em `node_modules\bulma\css\bulma.css` como também é possível encontrar os arquivos scss em `node_modules\bulma\sass\*`, daí me surge o seguinte questionamento

**Problema:**
Se eu quiser usar o arquivo *bulma.css* completo, eu deveria referenciar em meu html o caminho pra este arquivo lá no diretório `node_modules`? Ou seja, inserir em meu `<head>` a linha: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules\bulma\css\bulma.css">`?

Teoricamente faz sentido, afinal quem clonasse o projeto teria que rodar o `$npm install`, e aí teria a dependência exatamente nesse caminho, mas e se eu quiser dar build desse projeto? Eu teria que obrigatoriamente usar um ***task runner (gulp)*** que movesse uma cópia desse arquivo pra dentro de meu projeto?

Enfim, a maneira mais correta de como se fazer o uso dessas dependências me deixaram um pouco confuso, levando em consideração essas necessidades, qual a melhor prática a se adotar?

**P.S.:** Eu já faço uso do gulp no projeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens 3 alternativas:

- usar CDN, por exemplo `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.2.3/css/bulma.css`
- usar o ficheiro dentro no `node_modules`
- copiar para o teu projeto

A primeira opção é alternativa às outras duas. A segunda desaconselho e a terceira, juntamente com a segunda, é viável.

A razão pela qual se deve evitar usar ficheiros dentro do `node_modules` é porque se alguém fizer um upgrade dessa dependência os ficheiros antigos (que funcionavam) são alterados e não há como ver as mudanças. Tipicamente excluímos a diretoria toda no Github e as mudanças não são registadas.

Tendo uma cópia só uma ação humana propositada pode fazer o ficheiro mudar, e isso é mais seguro e dá menos bugs.

Para copiar tens várias alternativas. Ou copias à mão, por exemplo com um script assim:

```
var async = require('async');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
// funcão para copiar
function copy(from, to, cb){
    var cmd = ['cp', from, to].join(' ');
    exec(cmd, {
        cwd: __dirname + '/../'
    }, function(err){
        if (err) console.log('Copy failed.', err);
        else cb(err);
    });
}
// módulos que precisam ser copiados
function copyDatePicker(cb){
    async.series([
        function(next){
            copy(
                'node_modules/component-picker/lib/ComponentPicker.js',
                'public/javascript/ComponentPicker.js',
                next
            );
        }, function(next){
            copy(
                'node_modules/component-picker/lib/ComponentPicker.css',
                'public/css/ComponentPicker.css',
                next
            );
        }
    ], cb);
}
```

ou podes usar no código:

```
const biblioteca = require('minhaBiblioteca');
```

e depois compilar com webpack ou browserify e assim eles importam o código necessário para dentro de um novo ficheiro `.js` criado com o código todo.

Comment: Se eu optasse pela alternativa do CDN, nem precisaria instalar o framework como dependência certo? Pra mim só faz sentido instalar como dependência se eu fosse utilizar os arquivos `scss` para serem incluídos em meus estilos na medida do necessário ... estou correto?

Comment: @ViniciusColares exato. Se não precisas de os modificar e não precisas de trabalhar offline então CDN parece-me o mais simples.

Comment: @Sergio se o aconselhável é copiar os fontes para dentro de uma estrutura interna, qual é a vantagem da utilização do NPM para simplesmente baixar os pacotes? Sendo que se for baixar os pacotes individualmente eu posso fazer direto pelo Github ou baixar o bundle dos CDNs que inclusive vai me evitar de baixar diversos fontes desnecessários e de dependências que eu não necessariamente utilize. Neste quesito não estou vendo aplicação real para baixar as bibliotecas via npm. Fazendo um paralelo, eu achava que o npm criaria um autoload assim como o composer do php faz.